# Call class function from another class through pointer in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am a newbie trying to code a Menu class and I want it to be able to call functions that are part of other classes. I have sought thoroughly on the internet, but the answers that I've found doesn't fit my needs.

Here is a straightforward piece of code that defines my problem:

```
#include <iostream>

class Class1;//forward declaration
typedef void (Class1::*FunctionPtr_t)();//type: Pointer to a function in Class1 scope

class Class1
{
public:
    void function1()
    {std::cout << "function1 executed!";}//Test function to execute from Class2
};

class Class2
{    
public:
    FunctionPtr_t myfcnptr = NULL;//Pointer to a function in Class1
};

int main()
{
  Class2 myclass2;

  myclass2.myfcnptr = &Class1::function1;//Assign function to pointer (Everything OK here)
  (myclass2.*myfcnptr)();//Compilation Error: 'myfcnptr' was not declared in this scope
}
```

I have messed around, made both classes friend and used scope operators almost everywhere. I know the solution must be quite easy and that I'm making a ridiculous mistake, but I don't catch it! Thank you for your patience ;)

Comment: you need an object of `Class1` to call a member function of that class. Do you really need to mess around with function pointers?

Comment: you should explain better your original problem and what you want to achieve. This looks like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because it is not clear why you need function pointers and the code you posted makes (no offense) little sense to me

Comment: no offense intended ;). I am trying to create a menu for an Arduino project and each menu option triggers a function. The menu class is generic so it has to be capable of manage a generic array of functions, which will ultimately be specified in the construction process. However some of the functions belong to other classes. As an example, the menu access a database which is managed by a database class, though my menu class will be passed a reference to a function (for example readData) and has to be able to call it.

Comment: Are there any workaround to deal with this kind of situation? Please remember that as I am programming for an Arduino, I can't implement the Standard Library.

Comment: you would not need to implement the standard library, others did that already for you :P (unfortunately not available for arduino). What is "the situation"? What do you actually need? Calling a (non-static) member function without an object does not make sense in the first place.

Comment: the situation explained right above. The comment was too long and I had to split it in two parts. For don't having access to the SL, I was meaning just that, it isn't implemented for Arduino and I can't do that

Comment: oh sorry I actually overlooked that comment. You are using terms in a confusing way: You dont pass anything to a class but to an object. If in your database object you want to call a member function of some menu object, you should pass the object (and possibly a function pointer, but not a function pointer alone) and call the method on that object. On the other hand, if you dont need a menu object to call its method, then your design is flawed and that method should actually be static (or even a free function)

Comment: ...btw your comments should actually part of your question instead then I could post my comments as answer, comments are only meant for clarification but not for solving problems or discussions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `(myclass2.*myclass2.myfcnptr)();`.

But in your case, `Class1` and `Class2` are unrelated, so `Class2` cannot sensibly call a member function from `Class1`. You need an instance of `Class1`, or something derived from `Class1`, to perform that call.

Comment: SOLVED->Quite near!!! The correct syntax is `(myclass1.*myclass2.myfcnptr)();` , where `myclass1` is an instantiation of `Class1`. I'm sure you meant that, but anyway you pushed me in the right way ;) Thank you!!

Comment: @Leo I've split my answer between syntax and semantics, but maybe that makes it unclear...

Answer (score 1):

If no instantiation of Class1 is desired, it is also possible to make the method function1 `static` and call it directly from a Class2 instance. The following code will compile:

```
#include <iostream>


typedef void (*FunctionPtr_t)();//PAY ATTENTION TO THE NEW typedef !

class Class1
{
public:
    static void function1() //STATIC METHOD
    {std::cout << "function1 executed!";}//Test function to execute from Class2
};

class Class2
{    
public:
    FunctionPtr_t myfcnptr = NULL;//Pointer to a function in Class1
};

int main()
{
  Class2 myclass2;

  myclass2.myfcnptr = &Class1::function1;//Assign function to pointer
  (*(myclass2.myfcnptr))();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a member function via a member function pointer, but you are not specifying the instance of `Class1` to call against.

For example:

```
FunctionPtr_t func = &Class1::function1;
Class1 instance;
(instance.*func)();
```

Notice that I've had to specify the instance to call against. The pointer just references a function. This is different to languages like C# where you can reference a function and that reference also tracks the object containing the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you will need to create a relationship between the two classes `Class1` and `Class2` by utilizing C++'s class inheritance system; as previously mentioned, `Class2` simply cannot call a `Class1` member function without having a relationship. You could, perhaps, cause `Class2` to extend `Class1` by writing something like this on the first line of your class definition:

```
class Class2 : public Class1
{  // ...
```

You would also want to mark the original function in the parent class `Class1` as `virtual` and then provide a definition of the function in the child class `Class2`.

A good resource to learn about C++'s class inheritance, polymorphism, the `virtual` keyword, etc., would be http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/.